# Listbox Vertical Gap between Items (Remove??)

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, win-universal-app

My listboxes are data driven from Lists of objects with databinding using a DataTemplate eg:

```
            <ListBox x:Name="TheMainListBox" 
                 ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True" 
                 ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Height="540" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 Width="Auto"
                 Margin="0"
                 Padding="0"
                 Background="Yellow"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                 SelectionChanged="TheMainListBox_SelectionChanged" 
                 DoubleTapped="TheMainListBox_DoubleTapped"  
                 >
```

The template:

```
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid or Stackpanel Background="Blue"
                         Padding="0"                                    
                         BorderBrush="Black"
                         BorderThickness="1"
                         Margin="0"
                     >
                     .... Binding Textboxes/blocks
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I end up with a yellow container, the ListBox, .. with blue rectangles inside, the ListBox items but there is a vertical gap between them.  I can set a negative vertical-top margin but that is cruddy and doesn't work for the top item.  How can I reduce the vertical gap between items to zero.

If a create a ListBox with static items, each in a ListBoxItem container, eg:

```
                <ListBoxItem BorderThickness="1" Width="100" Height="50"
                  BorderBrush="Black" Background="Red"/>
```

It all works as required.

**So how can I get rid of the vertical spacing between items with the ItemTemplate/DataBinding?**
This is mission critical, thx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have time to load up a proj to test but you should be able to just kill the margin/padding that could cause it. So add;

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: @DavidJones Sure, ItemTemplate is just the Content being displayed via the ContentPresenter embedded in the ListBoxItem. The [ItemContainerStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle) on the other hand is for styling the actual Container aka the ListBoxItem itself and it's style template. Applied in the ItemTemplate you're effectively a child of ListBoxItem. Applied in the ItemContainer you're the parent of the ListBoxItem. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't thought a lot of why this could be happening, haven't digged into styles ither, and my answer doesn't look nice, but try `Margin="0,-2,0,-2"`

```
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid or Stackpanel Background="Blue"
                     Padding="0"                                    
                     BorderBrush="Black"
                     BorderThickness="1"
                     Margin="0,-2,0,-2"
                 >
                 .... Binding Textboxes/blocks
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: The problem with negative margins vertically is that the top item can get truncated or spill over to the element above.  For one context I have tried 
Margin="-12,-12,0,-12"
But I feel this is too much of a "fix".

Comment: @DavidJones, yes, it is a fix. If the answer of Chris W. works, then it is the one.

Answer (score 0):

properly setting the height of the ListBoxItem will solve the issue. Here is the code snippet

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="Your_Desired_Height"/>
 </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

For listbox please use Height property and for listview use MinHeight property. Replace the required height value in the Your_Desired_Height placeholder.